# How do I extract the first number that occurs after a matching pattern

Tags: r, regex

Consider these examples:

```
examples <- c(
  "abc foo",
  "abc foo 17",
  "0 abc defg foo 5 121",
  "abc 12 foo defg 11"
)
```

Here I would like to return the first number that occurs after "foo". In this case: NA, 17, 5, 11. How can I do this?  I tried using a look-behind, but with no luck.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(examples, "(?<=foo.*)[0-9]+")

Error in stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
  Look-Behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length. (U_REGEX_LOOK_BEHIND_LIMIT)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
str_match(examples, "foo.*?(\\d+)")

     [,1]          [,2]
[1,] NA            NA  
[2,] "foo 17"      "17"
[3,] "foo 5"       "5" 
[4,] "foo defg 11" "11"
```

From `?regex`:

> By default repetition is greedy, so the maximal possible number of repeats is used. This can be changed to ‘minimal’ by appending `?` to the quantifier.

From `?str_extract`:

> See Also
>
> `?str_match` to extract matched groups; `?stri_extract` for the underlying implementation.

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(examples, "foo"), function(x) str_extract(string = x[2], pattern = "\\d+"))` seems to work but I can't tell if it would always work

Answer (score 1):

You may use a [base R solution like this](https://ideone.com/urHZgF):

```
> res <- gsub(".*?foo\\D*(\\d+).*|.*", "\\1", examples)
> res[nchar(res)==0] <- NA
> res
[1] NA   "17" "5"  "11"
```

As the regex will always match any string, you do not need to run a regex replacement twice, just fill out empty values with NA as the second step.

The pattern matches:

- `.*?foo` - any 0+ chars as few as possible (since `*?` is lazy) up to the first occurrence of `foo` and then `foo` itself
- `\\D*` - zero or more non-digit chars
- `(\\d+)` - Group 1 that captures 1 or more digits (later, the value stored in the group can be referred with `\1` backreference)
- `.*` - the rest of the string
- `|` - OR
- `.*` - the whole string even if empty.

Answer (score 0):

Base R `gsub` can do it:

```
# pulls fist instance of a digit 
gsub('^\\D*(\\d*).*', '\\1', examples)
[1] ""   "17" "0"  "12"
```

Edit: actual solution using base R

```
ifelse(
     grepl('foo\\D*\\d', examples), 
     gsub('^\\D*(\\d+).*', '\\1', gsub('.*foo\\s*', '', examples)), 
     NA)
[1] NA   "17" "5"  "11"
```

Comment: `12` does not follow `foo` in the fourth case.

Comment: The regular expression returns the first string of digits, or the first string of digits after text, not the first string after `foo`. @Frank's solution is flawless

Comment: "*Here I would like to return the first number that occurs after "foo"*"

Comment: Understood. It's not a complete and exact solution.

Comment: Edited, to match desired output